# Why can users ask when their rep is 1?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, privileges

Whatever the question is, a lot of questions don't get answers because people seem uninterested in it. These questions have one particular thing in common: The user has only 1 rep as a starter, and, the question's time of asking is almost the same as the time when the account is made, so it looks like the account was made for that question only.

That means that people tend to think that the user will probably not follow up and may not even accept an answer. When it may look like the user made the account only for that question, and the question looks rushed, I thought that maybe users with 1 rep should not be able to ask.

I see the point of having them ask or answer at 1 rep, as Dimitri Mx pointed out in the answer below, but that is not exactly what I am trying to say. I am saying that just like tag wiki's low-rep-user edits, they are only visible to the poster until peer-reviewed.

Can we not maintain the site better if we implement that here on anime.stackexchange?

---

**EDIT:**

Let me just summarise what I want to say.

Why are first posts that are still in review queue visible on the main page? Just like tag wiki's, if a user has not enough reputation then it is only visible to the user himself/herself until peer reviewed. Similarly, if I don't have enough reputation and I edit a question, it will only be visible to me until peer reviewed.

So why aren't first posts treated in the same way?

Comment: Uninteresting as it seems, if they're on topic we should leave them. (or answer them if you know the answer) If you think it's not useful or low quality you can always downvote.

Comment: It's not like this site is being spammed with tons of low quality questions like StackOverflow. Rather, we would want as many questions as possible, and there are enough high rep users here to flag/vote to close the questions if they are not up to par. And I haven't seen any site that put up a barrier like that after the user registers for the site. It will drives users away for sure.

Comment: There's a review queue for new users already, and we generally deal with the queues quickly, so I suspect this would have relatively little practical effect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Say you have a question, burning away at you as you can't seem to find any answer regarding it on the web. However, you managed to find this site advertising as a Q&A specialized in the area you want to ask this question about. You take some time to register and end up with unable to ask your question as you start off with not enough reputation to ask.

*would you have used that site?* *I sure wouldn't have*.

Users with 1 reputation can ask questions, as that is what this site is meant for, Q&A. Everybody starts off with just 1 reputation, and reputation only gives an indication of how much the community trusts you. However keep in mind
[Reputation is entirely optional](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)

> **Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you;** it is earned by convincing your peers that you know what you’re talking about. The more reputation you earn, the more privileges you gain and the more tools you'll have access to on the site - at the highest privilege levels, you'll have access to many of the same tools available to the site moderators. That is intentional. We don’t run this site; the community does!

Nobody is perfect, and neither do we expect perfection in the first question asked, or any to follow. We hope people take the time to learn about A&M as a Q&A site through [our tour](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tour) and maybe even take the time to look through the [help center](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help). And over time develop the skills to ask good questions, and give good answers.

However, we as a community should try and help new members. Either by guiding them to the right resources, helping them by editing their questions to be acceptable by our norms, or pointing out through comments how they can improve.

This sometimes can be frustrating, as good answers might never be accepted. However, having an accepted answer or even gaining reputation should not be the goal. But as also mentioned on the about page:

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about anime and manga.

Answer (score 4):

There's no reason we should be gatekeeping new users from a Q&A, unless they are spamming, consistent posting poor quality content, or   something else that undermines the productivity if the site. Everyone should be given a chance to ask and answer questions on the Stack Exchange family of sites, regardless of age, race, or creed.

Certain site privileges need to be peer reviewed in order to maintain a consistent level of quality. Not everyone can be mature, it this applies many folds to fans of anime and manga fans as the demographic is made up of younger people.

The ability to ask and answer is the most basic of privileges given to new users so they go about using the site and it's community. A certain degree of trust is given to these new users that they will follow proper netiquette when going about asking and answering. By requiring new post to be peer review you remove this trust and assume most users are not up to your level standards. This is can be considered a selfish and may deter new users from joining and participating in your community. New users are the lifeblood of communities, without newcomer communities will stagnate. Users come and go all the time, like the wind. Sometimes they bring good things, other times the inverse is true. Its better to be welcoming to new users as you don't know what they might be able to bring to your community. Maybe they have a question about something you never thought about but find interesting, or maybe they asked something about a long forgotten series you enjoyed or forgot about.

We live in a world that's mostly about give and take. But there are times that its better to give first and take later. In our case, we are giving new users the opportunity to ask appropriate, on-topic questions freely, and perhaps have them answered just as freely. A few might stick around abd contribute to the site and community. It's an idealistic scenario, but we're not a serious community, nor are we treated as such other Stack Exchange communities. It's a place to take things easy and have some fun. We're a recreational Q&A site on the topic of imported Japanese media. Just as veteran fans don't have the right to tell other new or casual whether of not they are actual fans, we don't have the right to tell new users if they're questions/answers are acceptable or not.

Not everyone can ask or right good questions. Its up to the community to help the users. The Stack Exchange network is built upon the backs of their community. Elitism is abound on the bigger sites, but as we are now, we are neither big nor small. We're at a turning point, and its up to the community to decide what to do or how to go about from here.